# Android - can't hide `TextInputLayout`/`TextInputEditText` underline

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I am currently trying to hide the underline of a `TextInputEditText` when it is disabled. Here is how it looks with the [current implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uCWr.png). I want this same look, but without the underline. Here is the current XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:theme="@style/ProfileDetail.TextInputLayout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_background_profile_item"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAppearance="?textAppearanceBody2"
        android:enabled="false"
        tools:text="Jimmy" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The custom style:

```
<style name="ProfileDetail.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

What I have tried so far:

- Setting the theme of the `TextInputLayout` to a custom style with defined colorControlNormal
- Overriding the background of the `TextInputEditText` and/or `TextInputLayout` to be a solid color drawable

Most solutions online suggest using custom styles and setting colorControlNormal but that doesn't seem to do the trick for me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting the background to null for TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
         app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
         app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp">
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It goes away if you set the background colour to transparent:

```
yourEditText.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.transparent));
```

where:

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

**EDIT:** After Gabriele's comment I checked again in my project and I can verify that the above solution works for me, as long as I change the background on the TextInputEditText view directly and not through the TextInputLayout. I think the idea is that the colour replaces the background drawable that includes the underline, and since the colour is transparent the view blends with the background.

**EDIT 2:** Also what seems to work for me if you want to edit the containing layout instead is: `mTextInputLayout.setBoxBackgroundMode(TextInputLayout.BOX_BACKGROUND_NONE);`

Comment: The question is about the underline not the backgroud. In any case it is not correct. The `TextInputLayout` is a `LinearLayout`, not an `EditText` and the background is defined by `boxBackgroundColor`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I knew it was about the underline, but I thought the TextInputEditText carries the attributes about the underline, and in an example, I've tried in the past it worked this way. Maybe I was setting a null drawable instead. I couldn't test it when I made the post but I'll check it again in my project and either correct or remove my answer altogether.